# Model is moving while playing animation

Tags: animation

I have re-targeted an animation on my model and except the movement everything worked.

Problem is that model moves forward while the animation plays, it has to be stationary.

Here is example GIF:

[image]

Is there an option to fix this?

Here is the **Blender** file:

[image]

Comment: Please give us the .blend-file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Added file and updated question

Answer (score 1):

I've played around with the file, to me it seems that the "rigpelvis bone" has X and Y location keyframes that make the whole model "move". By muting them it seems better (but it's still not perfect to me... feet are still sliding, maybe they need to be animated differently... (I'm not a rigging expert)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I will look into this!